# ACF populate choises from database into the choices box in the backend

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

How can i fill the choises from the database instead of static? See attachement:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this function into my function.php, so i only have to add my options in a custum table,like countries for example.

```
function makeChoiceArrayForACF($postid){
    $datafromdbase = someFunctionToGetDataFromDbase();
    $newdbasearray = array();
    foreach ($datafromdbase as $key => $value){
        $newdbasearray[$key] = $key;
    }
    $new = array(
        'multiple' => 0,
        'allow_null' => 1,
        'choices' =>
            $newdbasearray,
        'default_value' =>
            array(),
        'ui' => 0,
        'ajax' => 0,
        'placeholder' => '',
        'return_format' => 'array',
        'type' => 'select',
        'instructions' => '',
        'required' => 1,
        'conditional_logic' => 0,
        'wrapper' =>
            array(
                'width' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'id' => '',
            ),
    );
    $my_post = array(
        'ID'           => $postid,
        'post_content' => serialize($new),
    );
    wp_update_post( $my_post );
}

add_action('init', 'admin_only');

function admin_only() {
    if( !is_admin() )
        return;
    makeChoiceArrayForACF(16611);
}
```